# Show history of changes to files based on a wildcard e.g. *.vcxproj

Tags: git

Somewhere, changes to a project file or similar is causing build issues but there have been a lot of changes from various branches and it's not immediately obvious where or when

Is there a way I can get git to simply list in reverse order, each time a file matching a wildcard has been modified, e.g. *.sln, *.vcxproj, so I can troubleshoot each commit more easily?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.**

Just filter your `log` with `-- <path> [<other/path>]` to restrict the commits output to the ones which modify (in any way, modification, creation, deletion...) said path(s). Wildcards are allowed. ([see doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---ltpathgt82308203))

```
git log -- *.sln *.vcxproj
```

And of course you can then throw in here any comfort options you want (here `--oneline` for example, but adapt to your needs), including `--reverse`. You'll also probably want to use `--all` to search on every branch, not only on the currently checked out one.

Just be sure to have **only paths** after the `--`, any option has to be given before it.

```
git log --reverse --oneline --all -- *.sln *.vcxproj
```

*(Note: double-quote your paths when they happen to contain whitespace)*
**(In some shells, even without whitespace, you'll also have to double-quote to avoid premature expansion of the wildcard)**

Comment: well the problematic change is _in_ my branch after a merge but from where, I don't know. It could be a merge with changes I have made that causes the problem... probably is, in fact. - and thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Mr.Boy If the problem **is** in your branch's history, merges included, it'll be found without `--all`. But in doubt, use `--all`, yes. Did you consider using `git bisect` to more specifically locate the "bad" commit?

Comment: That last note, about needing to use `"*.sln"`, is pretty important in some cases. :-) Also worth noting: `--follow`, which makes Git look for renamed files, only handles one file name at a time, so don't try to combine it with wildcards like this.

Comment: @torek Duly noted. Added emphasis.